# Is it possible to include a parent local.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, local.xml

I'm in the process of converting my company's web site to Magento 1.9. We've purchased a theme, but need to make some design changes such as adding javascript and css files to the header.

I'm new to Magento, but I believe that the changes we need to make would typically be made by modifying the local.xml file of the theme. My purchased theme, however, already has a very detailed local.xml. I'm hesitant to modify this because I assume it's likely to change if the theme is updated. I've tried overriding the layout under Config->Design->Themes->Layout, but when I create my own local.xml, of course the primary file is never loaded.

Is it possible for my overridden local.xml to indicate that the parent file should be ran as well? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do in general? I believe I could create a module that applies our layout changes, but that doesn't seem like the "right" way to do it.

Comment: See here in details http://inchoo.net/magento/using-local-xml-for-overriding-or-updating-xml-structure/

Comment: @Abdul the article doesn't answer the question and is a bit outdated (2010, way before Magento introduced theme inheritance with 1.9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for my overridden local.xml to indicate that the parent file should be ran as well?

No. Unfortunately for `local.xml` the same fallback mechanism applies as for all other theme files, i.e. the first one in the theme inheritance tree is used and there is no way to include a parent explicitly.

> Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do in general?

Yes, but it's still not ideal. Since Magento 1.9 you can use `theme.xml` for layout updates and it is actually the preferred way over `local.xml`. (Read more: https://erfanimani.com/dont-use-local-xml/)

If the purchased theme uses only `local.xml` and no layout updates in `theme.xml`, you can use `theme.xml` for your own changes. But note that `theme.xml` is loaded before `local.xml`, so if the order of actions matters, this might not work for you.

---

What if the parent uses `theme.xml` for layout updates as well? Now, the layout updates of parent `theme.xml` files are not loaded either, but since `theme.xml` works different than `local.xml`, there is a fix for that: https://github.com/ericthehacker/magento-themefallbackfix

And there is another option, which is probably **the "right" way**: You can also define layout **files** in `theme.xml`. You'll still need to copy these definition for child themes but that's only a few lines.

#### Example

`mytheme/default/etc/theme.xml`

```
<theme>
    <parent>base/default</parent>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mytheme_default><file>mytheme_default.xml</file></mytheme_default>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

`mytheme/child/etc/theme.xml`

```
<theme>
    <parent>mytheme/default</parent>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mytheme_default><file>mytheme_default.xml</file></mytheme_default>
            <mytheme_child><file>mytheme_child.xml</file></mytheme_child>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

Comment: My purchased theme didn't use a theme.xml file, so it should have been straightforward (thanks to your help!) Unfortunately I did have some trouble. The theme had its own child theme that it required I set as the default in the system config, so folder structure theme/default and theme/main, with "main" set as the default in config. When I added theme/mychild/etc/theme.xml it would break the theme as I can only set the parent to 'main' or 'default'.  I solved this by setting my parent to 'main' and creating theme/main/etc/theme.xml declaring default as its parent.